# Return data from struct using Numpy Array

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy, python-c-extension

I am writing Python C-extensions to a library and wish to return data as an Numpy Array.  The library has a function that returns data from a sensor into a C structure.  I would like to take the data from that structure and return it as a Numpy Array.

The structure definition in the library:

```
typedef struct rs_extrinsics
{
    float rotation[9];    /* column-major 3x3 rotation matrix */
    float translation[3]; /* 3 element translation vector, in meters */
} rs_extrinsics;
```

The function prototype:

```
void rs_get_device_extrinsics(const rs_device * device, rs_stream from_stream, rs_stream to_stream, rs_extrinsics * extrin, rs_error ** error);
```

Here is my code that is just trying to return the first value for now:

```
static PyObject *get_device_extrinsics(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyArrayObject *result;
    int dimensions = 12;

    rs_stream from_stream;
    rs_stream to_stream;
    rs_extrinsics extrin;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "iiffffffffffff", &from_stream, &to_stream, &extrin)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    result = (PyArrayObject *) PyArray_FromDims(1, &dimensions, PyArray_DOUBLE);
    if (result == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    rs_get_device_extrinsics(dev, from_stream, to_stream, &extrin, &e);
    check_error();
    result[0] = extrin.rotation[0];
    return PyArray_Return(result);
}
```

I get the following error on compile:

```
error: assigning to 'PyArrayObject' (aka 'struct tagPyArrayObject_fields') from incompatible type 'float'
result[0] = extrin.rotation[0];
          ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

PyArrayObject, apart from data, have multiple fields:

```
typedef struct PyArrayObject {
    PyObject_HEAD
    char *data;
    int nd;
    npy_intp *dimensions;
    npy_intp *strides;
    PyObject *base;
    PyArray_Descr *descr;
    int flags;
    PyObject *weakreflist;
} PyArrayObject;
```

You should get your data field data from your PyArrayObjects. Like this: `result->data[index];`  Also you need to cast your data to proper type indicated by `result->descr->type` character code. Also dims, you are passing to PyArray constructor should be of type `npy_intp *`, not int. Type of array in your case should be `NPY_DOUBLE`.

If you are calling your function from python (are you?), you better just passing list object from Python and use PyList C API to manage float sequence.

```
PyObject*list_of_floats;
PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "iiO", &from_stream, &to_stream, &list_of_floats);
```